# DynamoDB - how many indexes for sorting and single document retrieval

Tags: amazon-web-services, indexing, amazon-dynamodb

As I'm new to DynamoDB I have a question about indices and single document retrieval. Say I have a document structure like this:

```
{
    "id": "71a07b09",
    "user_id" "5603cdbaa9edb8afe31ff587de14c644",
    "timestamp": 1482235833.
    "data": {
        "param": "value"
    }
}
```

When creating a new table I will set one index on `user_id` and sort key on `timestamp` so I can query user's documents within a given time range.

The question is - if I would also like to query a single document by it's id (`71a07b09` in our example) - do I also need to set another index just on the `id` field? If so how would that affect my monthly AWS costs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need additional index (Global Secondary Index) if you have defined the Partition key as `user_id` and sort key as `timestamp`.

You can project only the required attributes to GSI to reduce the total number of bytes stored in GSI which in turn will reduce the code.

> Storage costs for a GSI are based on the total number of bytes stored
>   in that GSI. This includes the GSI key and projected attributes and
>   values, and an overhead of 100 bytes for indexing purposes.

The pricing varies based on the region. Refer the below link.

[DynamoDB pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/)

**Example for US-EAST (Ohio):**

First 25 GB stored per month is free

$0.25 per GB-month thereafter